# How to call a Function in ViewDidLoad with multiple parameters using Swift

Tags: swift, ios-homekit

I want to call a function in ViewDidLoad method with multiple parameters. But it shows the error

> Missing argument 'didFindNewAccessory'in call

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        addaccessory(self)
}

func addaccessory(browser: HMAccessoryBrowser, didFindNewAccessory accessory:HMAccessory){

        print("Found new accessory")
        home?.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: {
            error in
            if error != nil {

                print("Failed to add it to home")

            }else{
                print("Successfully Added")
                self.home?.assignAccessory(accessory, toRoom: self.room!, completionHandler: {
                    error in

                    if error != nil{
                        print("Unable to add to room")
                    }else{
                        print("Successfuly added to ropom")
                        self.findOrCreatedServioceGroup()
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: the function takes two arguments, you are calling it with only one `addaccessory(self)`, as the error message states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide the argument to your function `addaccessory`.
In your case you must have a `browser: HMAccessoryBrowser` and `accessory:HMAccessory`, that's why your call `addaccessory(self)` is wrong with invalid argument.
You should have something like this :

```
addaccessory(yourBrowser, didFindNewAccessory: yourAccessory)
```

Comment: Thanks @Manalalz: i was face this problem many time. thanks a lot Man.